# android canvas draw mysteriously clipped

Tags: android, drawing, canvas

My android app draws a chart on a Canvas.  It works fine in the simulator.  On a real device the chart is clipped to the left 1/5 of the screen.  I've tried:

canvas.clipRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Region.Op.REPLACE);

to clear the clipping.  Am I missing something?  Does layering have anything to do with this?

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0):

I changed my order of draw operations and the clip problem went away.  (It was superstition.)  The original problem gave results on a real device that clipped differently than the simulator.